# c# bindingsource filter datetime older than x days

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

i'm searching for a solution to filter a datagridview by a datetime field1 older than x days where x is another field2 from type short in the same row. In sql a possible syntax would be:

```
field1 < DATEADD(day, field2, GETDATE())
```

But i have to use the "Filter" property of [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) 
The DataGridView is bound to a BindingSource and the source bound to a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) filled from a sql database.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx for allowed expressions in a filter string

Comment: Is your data retrieved from SQL?

Comment: Yes but stored in memory in DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

What are you binding to the DataGridView? And how?

if you're binding to it in codebehind and your DataSource is a list of DateTimes:

```
List<DateTime> dtList; //list with datetimes
dtList.Where( a => DateTime.Now.Subtract(a) > TimeSpan.FromDays(1)); 
//More than 1 day ago
```

Provide more information and code snippets of your code if you want more accurate help.

EDIT 1:

If you're using a custom type with a datetime property:

```
List<CustomObject> objList; //list with Custom objects
objList.Where( a => DateTime.Now.Subtract(a.dateTimePropertyName) > TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
.Where(a => a.otherPropertyName == "ExampleValue"); 

DateGridViewName.DataContext = objList;
```

Comment: Thanks but im searching for a string based filter query of BindingSource "Filter" property with a bound DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

This will work against static data...

```
DataTable filtered = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(
    x => x.Field<DateTime>("field1") < DateTime.Today.AddDays(x.Field<int>("field2"))).
    CopyToDataTable();

bindingSource1.DataSource = filtered;
```

However, if I understand what you want (data binding), while there *may* be a way to do it in a DataTable, it sounds like a job for a domain object instead.

```
class BoundDataObject
{
    public DateTime Field1 { get; set; }
    public short Field2 { get; set; }
    public bool PassFail
    {
        get { return Field1 < DateTime.Now.AddDays(Field2); }
    }
}
```

Loading the data into the domain object may be slightly more effort than the Data Table, but it's a one-time cost, and I think you will reap the benefits pretty quickly.